# I am getting following error.i download oracle client and provide necessary path to env variables

Tags: python, django, oracle10g, cx-oracle, instantclient

> import cx_Oracle
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Answer (score 0):

I'll list the things that you need to check.

1) An Oracle client is required. The easiest to use is the Oracle instant client which you can get from this location: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html

2) If Python is 64-bit, the Oracle client needs to be 64-bit and cx_Oracle needs to be 64-bit. If Python is 32-bit, the Oracle client needs to be 32-bit and cx_Oracle needs to be 32-bit. You can't mix and match!

3) The client needs to be in the PATH environment variable. No other environment variables (like ORACLE_HOME) should be set.

You can use the "depends" tool (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to help determine why Windows is refusing to load that DLL.

Comment: In 2) you may want a 32-bit Oracle client to go with Python 32-bit. (The current text reads:  ... the Oracle client needs to be 64-bit ...)

Comment: Every software i am using is 64 bit.i had copyd oracle client in my python35 folder and provide path in env variable.but still getting same error again and again

Comment: I have also added information about "depends" which can help you figure out what the problem is.